# VB.Net - Filter date list uniques discarding time

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim months As New List(Of Date)
months = months.Distinct().ToList()
```

This filters very unique dates because of time difference.
I want to filter dates discarding times but only considering unique elements with month and year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take just the year and month from each date, and find the distinct values from that.

```
months = months.Select(Function(x) New Date(x.Year, x.Month, 1)).Distinct().ToList()
```

Comment: Perfect! I tried the same thing with .Find() method but I didn't know .Select() method. Thanks a lot.